# How to retrieve column names which are byte and not null in C# json web service using LINQ class?

Tags: json, linq, web-services, c#-4.0

My `.edmx` file is `gpcb1.edmx` and class is `tbl_Compulsory_Attachments`

I know the properties of class are there but how to make it working?

I have database table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Compulsory_Attachments](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Industry_Id] [int] NULL,
[Forward_letter] [image] NULL,
[Form1] [image] NULL,
[Form1a] [image] NULL,
[Pre_rpt] [image] NULL,
[Project_plan] [image] NULL,
[Parking_plan] [image] NULL,
[EIA_rpt] [image] NULL,
[Mining_Plan] [image] NULL,
[Other_documents] [image] NULL,
[Declaration_page] [image] NULL,
[Project_subtype_masterid] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
)...
```

How to retrieve the column names which are byte and not null in C# json web service using LINQ Entity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following method

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Get Attachment fields which are byte and not null from industryid in compulsory attachements table") ,]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public String GetAttachmentFields(int Industry_Id)
{
    List<tbl_Compulsory_Attachments> attlist = new List<tbl_Compulsory_Attachments>();
    attlist = gpcb1.tbl_Compulsory_Attachments.Where(m => m.Industry_Id == Industry_Id).ToList();

    int i = 0;

    foreach (tbl_Compulsory_Attachments att in attlist)
    {
       foreach(var prop in att.GetType().GetProperties())
       {
           if (prop.Equals(null) || prop.Name.Equals("EntityState") || prop.Name.Equals("EntityKey") || prop.Name.StartsWith("tbl_"))
           {
           }
           else
           {
               if (prop.PropertyType.ToString().Equals("System.Byte[]"))
               {
                   if((byte[])prop.GetValue(att,null) !=null)
                   {
                        i += 1;
                   }
               }
           }
       }

    }
    Field[] fieldarray = new Field[i];
    int j = 0;
    foreach (tbl_Compulsory_Attachments att in attlist)
    {
        foreach (var prop in att.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Equals(null) || prop.Name.Equals("EntityState") || prop.Name.Equals("EntityKey") || prop.Name.StartsWith("tbl_"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.ToString().Equals("System.Byte[]"))
                {
                    if ((byte[])prop.GetValue(att, null) != null)
                    {
                        fieldarray[j] = new Field
                        {
                            id = j+1,
                            Fieldname = prop.Name
                        };
                        j += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(fieldarray);
    return strJSON;
    //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(indarray, Formatting.Indented);
}

public class Field
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String Fieldname { get; set; }
}
```